# Using regex expression in a Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jqgrid

I'm currently using the plugin [JqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) (version 4.6.0 - jQuery Grid) and I'm using some fields to be able to filter my results. Here is how look the GUI :

[image: Look of the GUI]

I have the big list of employees, and I would like to be able to filter them.
For now, it's working quite okay, I put the `postData` feature of JqGrid, so I'm able to filter with this piece of code :

```
$("#employeesList").jqGrid({
    autowidth: true,
    url: "getEmployees.htm",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    colNames:['<span>' + "Login" + '</span>',
              '<span>' + "First name" + '</span>',
              '<span>' + "Last name" + '</span>',
              '<span>' + "email" + '</span>',
              '<span>' + "Department" + '</span>',
              '<span>' + "Archived" + '</span>',
              '<span>' + "Actions" + '</span>'
              ],
    colModel: [ {name: 'login', index: 'login', width: 50, resizable: false},
                {name: 'firstName', index: 'firstName', width: 50, resizable: false},
                {name: 'lastName', index: 'lastName', width: 50, resizable: false},
                {name: 'email', index: 'email', width: 60, resizable: false},
                {name: 'department', index: 'department', width: 50, resizable: false},
                {name: 'archived', index: 'archived', width: 30, resizable: false},
                {name: 'actions', index: 'actions', width: 30, formatter:actionFormatter, sortable: false, resizable: false, fixed: true}
               ],
    hiddengrid: false,
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum : 25,
    jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
    rowTotal: 2000,
    rowList: paginationsAsArray,
    rownumbers: false,
    viewrecoreds: true,
    autoencode: true,
    toppager : true,
    pgbuttons : true,
    postData: {
        firstName: function() {
            return $("#filterFirstName").val();
        },
        lastName: function() {
            return $("#filterLastName").val();
        },
        department: function() {
            return $("#filterDepartment :selected").val();
        }
    }
});
```

And basically, when I fill some filters input and I click on `Filter` here is what happens :

`<a class="btn margin-bottom-10" onclick="reloadEmployeeTable()">Filter</a>`.

```
function reloadEmployeeTable() {
    $("#employeesList").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Unfortunately, theses filters needs exact match, which is not really conveniant ...

For example, when I search `asd`, here is my result :

[image: Search that works]

And I would like to have the same answer (and maybe other) when I type `*sd`

[image: Not working]

How to be able, in the `postData` feature, to implements a regex filter. In order to make these filters more useful than *match exactly*

Thanks in advance for your help,

Best Regards.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't included any JavaScript code which would show what you do. How you create jqGrid? Which `datatype` you use? Do you make filtering *on the client side* or on the server side? Which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in which version? jqGrid allows to implement case insensitive matching for the part of words or to use regex matching, but the solution depends on many detains which are unknown in your current question.

Comment: see the edit, I add the version of jqGrid, how I can my data and basically what happens when I click "Filter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `datatype: "json"` **without** `loadonce: true` parameter. So the paging, sorting and filtering will be implemented **on the server side**. jqGrid (in such configuration) just send the data (`firstName`, `lastName`, `department`) to the server and don't implement any filtering of the data. Thus you have to modify *your server code* (see `url` parameter of jqGrid) to implement regex filtering instead of exact matching.

jqGrid have [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) method (which you can use with with `defaultSearch: "cn"` option) which can help to implement filtering of the data. If you would use *local data* (or `loadonce: true`) then you can use *local* filtering and you can easy implement your requirements. You can use the way it the size of the data in not large (for example less then 10000 rows or data).

Comment: I will indeed pass the parameter to my Service and filter them directly there. :) Thanks for pointing this :).